# Foursquare venue photos API returns incorrect count?

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to pull all recent photos of a certain venue by using the following endpoint (limit 500 as the max suggested by the API):

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{venu_id}/photos?v=20120319&client_id={cient_id}&client_secret={cilent_secret}&group=venue&limit=500

I'm only pulling public photos (group=venue) but it's a venue with 17k+ check-ins so there should be enough data to pull.

However, in the response,

photos->count = 502

and the actual count of photos->items is 200.

In addition, when I change the offset to 200, it looks like that I can get photos before the latest 200 photos.

So, is this a documentation error, that the limit should 200 instead of 500? and what does photos->count = 502 means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to be a documentation error. Will update the docs accordingly. Thanks for bringing it to our attention!